# Is it possible to export glTF models vertices, UVs and normals with signed short "2 bytes", not float "4 bytes"?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, short, gltf

I had exported a glTF model from blender, when I put .bin file to hex editor, it seems his vertices, UVs and normals are in "4 bytes" float, or IEEE 754 floating point, like the example below.

Is it possible to export glTF models with short_signed not float, or "2 bytes" only, not "4 bytes" in the vertices, UVs and normals?

```
Example:

Vertices are in float:
X = 34 80 45 C2 ----short_signed----> xx xx
Y = C1 F9 65 42 ----short_signed----> xx xx
Z = 94 F6 76 41 ----short_signed----> xx xx

UVs are in float:
X = AD 69 0E 3F ----short_signed----> xx xx
Y = 5D FE 63 3F ----short_signed----> xx xx

Normals are in float:
X = 66 96 66 BF ----short_signed----> xx xx
Y = 56 66 DE 3E ----short_signed----> xx xx
Z = 00 00 80 3F ----short_signed----> xx xx
```

If it is impossible, please give me any method to convert this "4 bytes" float hexadecimal to "2 bytes" only, and make it short?  (IEEE 754 floating point --------> signed short)

Or is there another model format with signed short, or "2 bytes" in the vertices, UVs and normals?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Blender's exporter does not give full control over the binary data layout, the glTF format have some flexibility for allowing uint16, int16, and other array types. You can get pretty close to the result you're asking for with a tool that does quantization, [gltfpack](https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer/tree/master/gltf):

```
gltfpack -i input.glb -o output.glb -vn 14
```

As of gltfpack v0.14, by default normals are **int8**; the `-vn 14` option above changes that to **int16**. By default vertex positions are **uint16**, and UVs are **int16**. Note that this tool also interleaves vertex attributes.

Comment: Hi Mr. Don, thanks a lot, I'm noob in coding, I don't know how to use this gltfpack, can you tell me how is the method step by step please.
This is an example model obj, and the converted glTF 2.0 model ".bin", and an excel file for how the model must be in the final result: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k3rFwKaNitVmQX2VqfTXMjeiqBGRfWU7
Can you please convert it from float "4-bytes" to short_signed "2-bytes", with gltfpack.

Comment: See [installation instructions for gltfpack](https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer/tree/master/gltf#installation) then you only have to run the command above, with `input.glb` replaced by your `.gltf` filename. Note that this will make your positions, normals, and UVs **uint16, int16, and int16**, which is slightly different than you've asked for. I don't know of an easy way to get **int16 x 3** with an off-the-shelf tool.

Comment: If you want to file a feature request on https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform or https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer, I think there's a decent chance someone can help you, but you may need to wait a while.